# Distance from point $D$ to $BI$

Tags: geometry

[image]

I found that : $BI = 2\sqrt 2, DI = \sqrt 5, DB = 2\sqrt 2$. It means $\triangle BDI$ is isosceles triangle. Lets say $B$ to $DI$ is $a = \sqrt {BI^2 - ( \frac 12 DI)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{27}{4}}$. Lets say $t$ is distance from D to BI.

$t. BI = a. DI$

$t = \frac{\sqrt{27}}{4}$.

But why my answer not in the options?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $BI = \sqrt5$. So, △BDI is isosceles with DI = BI instead. Then, I to DB is 
$a = \sqrt {BI^2 - ( \frac 12 DB)^2} = \sqrt{3}$ and

$$t = \frac{DB}{BI}a = \frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt5}\cdot\sqrt3=\frac{\sqrt{24}}5$$

Comment: If therea no answer, means the question is error?